# Is it possible to combine org.immutable:value's builders with hibernate's @Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, immutables-library

I really like immutables.github.io's immutables:value annotation processor (`@Value.Immutable`, `@Value.Modifiable`, et al).    I have a project using hibernate with quite a few entities.  I'd love to have builders generated for me by the immutables library. Has anyone had any luck achieving this?

Say I have an entity

```
@Entity 
public class Entity { 
    @Column String value; 
}
```

There are a couple of general approaches that seem kind of sensible:

- Somehow tell `@Value.Modifiable` to apply the annotations to the concrete `ModifiableEntity` type instead of the soon-to-be abstract `Entity` class.
- Tell hibernate to use a different concrete class (somewhat akin to `@JsonDeserialize(as=ModifiableEntity.class)`).

But I can't work out how to achieve either of those approaches.  Does anyone know of an approach that might work?

Comment: are you aware of Hibernate's @Immutable annotation?
 https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html

Comment: @dimitrisli: Doesn't appear to be related to the immutables-library.

Comment: no it's not. therefore this is a comment and not an answer.